# How do I change $PATH to default on a mac?

Tags: bash, macos

I am a newbie to UNIX programming and I wanted to install Sqlpackage. So I followed the instructions on the Microsoft site:
1) Download sqlpackage for macOS.
2)To extract the file and launch sqlpackage, open a new Terminal window and type the following commands:

```
`$mkdir sqlpackage
$ unzip ~/Downloads/sqlpackage-osx-<version string>.zip ~/sqlpackage 
$ echo 'export PATH="$PATH:~/sqlpackage"' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ source ~/.bash_profile
$ sqlpackage`
```

I only skipped the second line, because it came already unzipped after the download, so I simply placed it into the new directory. But nothing happened, I couldn't launch sqlpackage from the terminal, I got 'command not found'. So I tried it aging. I have no idea how did I get there but now when I open a new terminal and enter $PATH this is what I get '

```
 Air-Anna:~ anna$ $PATH
    -bash: ~/sqlpackage:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin: No such file or directory
```

'

I opened the /.bash_profile with vim via the terminal and this is what it looks like

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/sqlpackage"
export PATH="$PATH:~/sqlpackage"
export PATH="$PATH:~/sqlpackage-osx-x64"
export PATH="$PATH:~/sqlpackage"
export PATH="~/sqlpackage" 
export PATH="$PATH:~/sqlpackage"
export PATH="~/sqlpackage"
export PATH="$PATH:~/sqlpackage"
export PATH="~/sqlpackage"
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
"~/.bash_profile" 10L, 361C
```

'
Seems like a mess what should I do?

Comment: You *always* get a "No such file or directory" if you run `$PATH` as a command. If you want to print the current value, use `echo "$PATH"` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename your `~/.bash_profile` file by running the following in Terminal:

`rm ~/.bash_profile`

and restart the Terminal. This should restore the system default path for you. To view the current value of `PATH` variable, type:

`echo $PATH`

in the Terminal. Do not simply type `$PATH` at the prompt as it would expand the value of the `PATH` variable and try to run it as a command.

To make the `sqlpackage` command available in your command PATH, add the sqlpackage files as instructed under a directory named sqlpackage in your Home directory, and then run the following on the Terminal:

`export PATH="$PATH:~/sqlpackage"' >> ~/.bash_profile`

followed by:

`source ~/.bash_profile`

This should set you up.

Comment: `/usr/bin:/bin` etc should already be in the path and should not need setting in `.bash_profile`.

Comment: Note that there's no reason for the `export`s -- any variable that is already exported before you update it will export the updated value by default; and since there's always a PATH set before your shell starts on any reasonable system, it's *always* exported by default.